# How to mmap/load a file in memory in python and acces to it from another process?

Tags: python, pointers, malloc, shared-memory

I know that in C there is a way to load files in memory with **mmap** and access them from another process.
Is there a way to do the same with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C's [`malloc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function has no way to "load files". You probably mean [`mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) instead.

Python does have mmap support. See the documentation at [mmap - Memory-mapped file support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) where there's an example as well.